# get list index id from div element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How do I get the id of each list index?

debugging in firebug shows:

```
    <li class="droptrue ui-draggable" style="display: list-item;">
    "...text of the li..."
    </li>
```

I'm passing a unique id to each list element.
Here is a scaled down sample in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/n2learning/tV4n7/89/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `id` attribute will not cloned. So change it to something else e.g. `data-id` could solve your problem.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/tV4n7/96/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How would I reference the data-id in javascript or jQuery? Would I still use $(this).attr('id');?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul#routinefilter li').each(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an array with all the ID's:

```
var ids = [];
$('#routinefilter li').each(function () {
  ids.push(this.id);
});
```

Or maybe easier to use later, attach to data()

```
$('#routinefilter li').each(function () {
  $(this).data('id', this.id);
});
```

The data attribute seems to stick, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tV4n7/97/)

Use data instead of ID !

Answer (score 1):

Add a callback for your `draggable`.

```
$(".droptrue").draggable({
    snap: '#dropTargetframe',
    connectToSortable: '#dropTargetframe',
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: false,
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
    }
});
```